# Rename subtitles of a list using a loop

Tags: r

I do have to rename sublist titles within a main matrix list called `l1`. Each Name(n) is related to a value as a character string. Here is my code :

```
names(l1)[1] <- Name1
names(l1)[2] <- Name2
names(l1)[3] <- Name3
names(l1)[4] <- Name4
## ...
names(l1)[43] <- Name43
```

As you can see, I have 43 sublists.  Is there a way do do that using an automated loop like `for (i in 1:43)` or something ? I tried to perform a loop but I am a beginner and that's very hard for now.

Edit : I would like to rename the elements of my list without having to type 43 lines manually. Here is the first three elements of my list :

```
str(l1)
List of 43
 $ XXX                      : num [1:640, 1:3] -0.83 -0.925 -0.623 -0.191 0.155 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "EV_BICYCLE" "HW_DISTANCE" "NO_ASSETS"
 $ XXX                                 : num [1:640, 1:2] -0.159 0.485 -0.686 -0.245 -3.361 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "HOME_OWN" "METRO_DISTANCE"
 $ XXX                      : num [1:640, 1:3] -0.79 1.15 0.224 0.388 -1.571 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "BICYCLE" "HOME_OWN_SC" "POP_SC"
```

That is to say, I would like to replace the 43 XXX by Name1, Name2 ... to Name43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
names(l1) <- unlist(mget(ls(pattern="^Nom_F")))
str(l1, list.len=2)
 #List of 3
 # $ Accessibility : int [1:5, 1:5] 10 10 3 9 7 6 8 2 7 8 ...
 # ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 # .. ..$ : NULL
 #  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
 # $ Access        : int [1:5, 1:5] 6 4 10 5 9 8 9 4 7 1 ...
 #..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 # .. ..$ : NULL
 # .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
```

Instead of creating separate objects, you could create a `vector` of real titles.  For example

```
 v1 <- LETTERS[1:3]
 names(l1) <- v1
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
l1 <- setNames(lapply(1:3, function(x)
          matrix(sample(1:10, 5*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5,
             dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1:5]))), rep('XXX',3))

Nom_F1 <- "Accessibility"
Nom_F2 <- "Access"
Nom_F3 <- "Poverty_and_SC"
```

Comment: That's totally working. Thank you very much. I will clean up some useless comments.